# How to add Cards to microsoft teams bot using Bot Framework SDK for Java?

Tags: java, botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm using the [Java botbuilder](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-java) to build a microsoft teams bot. I want to add [Cards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/cards/cards-actions) to my bot (e.g. to embed links, quick replies, and images).

In the above link it says: suggested actions are not supported in Microsoft Teams: if you want buttons to appear on a Teams bot message, use a card.

However, I can find no documentation on how to add a 'card' to the `Activity` schema.

I tried:

**1. Using suggested actions**

> I tried adding my `List<CardAction>` to the `SuggestedActions`
>   field in `Activity` but they were not rendered by microsoft teams
>   (as expected, the documentation says this is not supported).

**2. Using Attachments**

> I suspect it could be done using attachments, but can only find
>   documentation for the C#/JS versions (e.g.
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-send-rich-cards?view=azure-bot-service-3.0).

So I want to know how to add 'a card' to `Activity` schema so it can be rendered by my bot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BotFramework Java SDK is still in preview, so there isn't a lot of documentation I can point you towards. However, here is an example of adding a HeroCard to a reply.

```java
Activity reply = new Activity()
        .withType(ActivityTypes.MESSAGE)
        .withRecipient(activity.from())
        .withFrom(activity.recipient())
        .withAttachments(Arrays.asList(
                new Attachment()
                        .withContentType("application/vnd.microsoft.card.hero")
                        .withContent(new HeroCard()
                                .withTitle("Hero Card")
                                .withSubtitle("BotFramework")
                                .withButtons(Arrays.asList(new CardAction()
                                    .withValue("https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/")
                                    .withTitle("Get started")
                                    .withType(ActionTypes.OPEN_URL)
                                ))
                                .withImages(Collections.singletonList(new CardImage()
                                        .withUrl("https://sec.ch9.ms/ch9/7ff5/e07cfef0-aa3b-40bb-9baa-7c9ef8ff7ff5/buildreactionbotframework_960.jpg"))))

        ));
```

You can also take a look at the SDK [Attachment Tests](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-java/blob/14d8a346d52fe54703afd334e9228381dca133e7/libraries/bot-connector/src/test/java/com/microsoft/bot/connector/ConversationsTest.java#L214) for more examples.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This works. Images/links are rendered nicely. Just the 'suggested actions' (i.e. quick replies) aren't as nice with cards vs. suggested actions.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Yea as you mentioned teams does not support Suggested Actions, but they should work fine in channels like Web Chat and Facebook Messenger.